What tag should we use for brick and mortar store payments?
We just had another inquiry about accepting payments in a physical store: How would a restaurant accept Bitcoin?
We have a few of them already:

What is necessary for a Hotel to accept Bitcoin as a payment method?
Is Bitcoin suitable for fast transactions, eg in shops?
How do I accept bitcoin payments at a real world store?
How do BTC payments work at real-world shops?

But they are hard to find because they don't have a common tag. What would be the best tag for payments in a brick and mortar store?

Keep it simple.

face-to-face

Covering all situations where two people meet in person and have a cryptocurrency transaction.

Thanks, I was thinking about a lot of different ways of putting it, but this one got me on the right track. I went with [tag:face-to-face-payment].
